unresolved external symbol
Знаю, что такой вопрос уже был задан ранее до меня, но данные ответы там, мою проблему не решают.
При запуске программы и попытке записи в news.Read_Bufer.out[n_byte] возникает ошибка unresolved external symbol (news / _news). При этом, если я попробую взять массив из любого другого класса из другого hpp, при условии, что я добавлю #include и extern, по нему ошибок не будет. Если я скопирую код объединения union с массивом из другого hpp в мой и попробую это запустить, изменив только названия выдаст такую же ошибку.
Пробовал менять названия, потому что боялся, что компилятор может из-за них выдавать ошибку. Засовывал struct в union, короче крутил-вертел, но толку 0, ошибка остается.
//hpp

#ifndef __newscreen_HPP__
#define __newscreen_HPP__

class newscreen {
public:
int variable_func(int, int);
void init_func(void);


struct ByteSeq {
unsigned char FHH;
unsigned char FHL;
unsigned char BC;
unsigned char CMD;
unsigned char ADRSH;
unsigned char ADRSL;
unsigned char NUM;
unsigned char BYTE1H;
unsigned char BYTE1L;
unsigned char BYTE2H;
unsigned char BYTE2L;
};

union dataRxBuf {
unsigned char out [10];
ByteSeq in;
};

dataRxBuf Read_Bufer;
};

#endif

//cpp

#include newscreen.hpp

//какие-то функции
extern newscreen news;

__interrupt void IRQ_UART_4_RX(void){
static unsigned char n_byte = 0;
unsigned char = byte;
byte = RDR04;   //recieving data from MCU

if (n_byte <= 10){
news.Read_Bufer.out[n_byte] = byte;
n_byte++;
}
}


Ну а где extern newscreen news; без extern?

@Harry , не очень понял. В cpp файле присутствует extern. Когда я пробовал подключать массивы из других hpp , я подключал другие extern, сейчас они удалены, т.к. никакие другие hpp файлы я не использую.

Просто один раз в .cpp определите переменную newscreen news; У вас везде сказано одно — "потом линковщик переменную найдет, компилируй! — но нигде этой переменной так и нет.

после extern я добавил newscreen news; и ошибка ушла, это все хорошо. Но почему тогда если я беру массив other.Rx_Bufer.out[n_byte] = byte, предварительно пишу `include "Other.hpp" "extern Other other;" и все сразу работает без дополнительных определений? Это странности компилятора или что-то более умное?

Без конкретного кода ничего не могу сказать...
